# New-PartnerCustomerOrder for New Commerce Experience

Tags: c#, powershell, rest

I am trying to use [the `New-PartnerCustomerOrder` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/partnercenter/new-partnercustomerorder?view=partnercenterps-3.0) from the Microsoft Partner Center PowerShell module to create new commerce experience orders for customers, however, I am unable to set the `TermDuration` and `RenewsTo` / `CustomTermEndDate` fields.

You will note that I am using this resource, as documented by Microsoft in their `New-PartnerCustomerOrder` documentation: `Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Models.Orders.PSOrderLineItem`

I am unable to find any references to what properties that can be set but I did find this C# version in Microsoft's knowledge base: `Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.Models.Orders.OrderLineItem` which gives me a get and set for each field.

When I try to use these fields, I get these errors:
`'TermDuration' is a ReadOnly property.`
`The property 'CustomTermEndDate' cannot be found on this object.`

Here is my code:

```
$lineItem = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Models.Orders.PSOrderLineItem
$lineItem.LineItemNumber = 0
$lineItem.OfferId = ($Catalog | Where-Object {$_.OfferName -eq $Subscription.OfferName}).OfferId
$lineItem.Quantity = $Subscription.Quantity
$lineItem.TermDuration = "P1Y"
$lineItem.CustomTermEndDate = $Alignment

New-PartnerCustomerOrder -BillingCycle Monthly -CustomerId $clientId -LineItems @($lineItem)
```

I am expecting to be able to place an order and set the alignment date as well as the term and billing cycle. I know Microsoft has an API for doing this but I have not had much success with that route either and a lot more complex than this one.

**Updated Code**

```
$lineItem = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Models.Orders.PSOrderLineItem
    $lineItem.LineItemNumber = 0
    $lineItem.OfferId = ($Catalog | Where-Object {$_.OfferName -eq $Subscription.OfferName}).OfferId
    $lineItem.Quantity = $Subscription.Quantity
    $lineItem.ProvisioningContext.Add('duration', '1Year')
    $lineItem.FriendlyName = "$($Subscription.OfferName) - 1YM"

New-PartnerCustomerOrder -BillingCycle Monthly -CustomerId $clientId -LineItems @($lineItem)
```

The above code allows me to set the billing cycle and the term. However, I am still trying to discover a way to set the renewal date (alignment date to the end of the month) as specified when creating a New Commerce Experience subscription.

Comment: `[PSOrderLineItem]` appears to have a constructor that takes an instance of `[OrderLineItem]` - so you can create an `[OrderLineItem]` object, set the properties you need, and then do `$psOrderLineItem = [PSOrderLineItem]::new($orderLineItem)`

Comment: That returns the following error: Unable to find type [PSOrderLineItem].

Comment: You'll have to use the full type name (eg. `[Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Models.Orders.PSOrderLineItem]`), and make sure you've imported the PartnerCenter module. I was just shortening it to make the comment more readable :)

Comment: That worked for creating the PSOrderLineItem. However, the original error persists: 'TermDuration' is a ReadOnly property.

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76682827/edit), easier to format code there than in the comments :) FWIW `New-Object PSObject` creates an object of type `PSObject` - not an object of type `OrderLineTime`

Comment: How am I to construct the code? OrderLineTime doesn't work as a New-Object without referencing the -TypeName. That takes me back to the Read-only Error. Is there some documentation on this that I can follow for creating new Orders using this method? Again, my goal is to have the ability to set the Term Duration, the billing cycle, and the date that the subscription renews.

Comment: I suspect that the API uses init-only properties - properties that can only be set with an object initializer in C# - PowerShell doesn't have any such mechanism to hook into object instantiation, so you'll either have to resort to using reflection, or you'll have to write some C# and call that from PowerShell